# How should I write function parameters to enforce a move rather than a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, move-semantics

I want to move a large container from a return value into another class using that class' constructor. How do I formulate the parameter to ensure that it doesn't end up being copied?

```
/* for the sake of simplicity, imagine this typedef to be global */
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> umap;

umap foo()
{
    umap m; /* fill with lots of data */
    return m;
}

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(umap m) : bm(m) { }
private:
    umap bm;
};

Bar myBar(foo()); // run foo and pass return value directly to Bar constructor
```

Will above formulation trigger the appropriate behavior, or do I need to specify the constructor's parameters as rvalue-references, the way containers do for their own move-semantics?

```
public:
    Bar(umap&& m) : bm(m) { }
```

or

```
public:
    Bar(umap&& m) : bm(std::move(m)) { }
```

...?

Comment: I think Scott Meyer commented on this here : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler#!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to support moving *and* copying, the easiest way would be [to pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/):

```
Bar(umap m) : bm(std::move(m)) { }
```

Now you can construct `Bar` from both an lvalue and an rvalue:

```
umap m;
Bar b1(m);               // copies
Bar b2(std::move(m));    // moves
Bar b3(make_umap());     // moves
```

If you *only* want to support rvalues, then use an explicit rvalue reference:

```
Bar(umap && m) : bm(std::move(m)) { }
```

The `std::move` is always necessary, since `(m)` is always an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

Enforce passing of rvalue into the constructor and also make sure to move the map, like this:

```
Bar(umap &&m) : bm(std::move(m)) {}
```

#### Starting with the first example, to the above solution:

Let's start with the first example of `Bar(umap m) : bm(m) {}`. This will perform at least 1 copy, maybe 2.

`bm(m)` will always copy. `m` here is *lvalue* even though it's **bound** to *an rvalue*. To make it move, you must wrap it in `std::move` to turn it back into an *rvalue*. We get `bm(std::move(m))`.

`Bar(umap m)` might copy. The value will be moved in if it's an *rvalue*, but will be copied if it's an *lvalue*. Since we want to prevent all copies, we need to only let *rvalue* bind. We get `Bar(umap && m)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above:

What I see in your example is a classical case for "copy elision" optimization.

[What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

An actual compiler needs no support from you to optimize the things away and there is no must to deal yourself with rvalue references in this special case of return value optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you use `std::move`. If you need C++03 compatibility you can *default-construct* `bm` via `:bm()` and then use `using std::swap; swap(bm, m);`.